# Read only file system on SDXC UHS card

Tags: sd-card, ubuntu-mate, card-reader

When I used gimp to save a file to a SDXC UHS card, I got this message.

```
Read only file system.
```

The card was in a slot on my printer.

I used chown to make me owner with read/write permissions.

```
drwxrwxrwx 1 andy andy 131072 Dec 31 1969 3563-3531
```

3/13/19 Update

I can write to the SDXC UHS card when card is inserted into card reader on my desktop. Maybe the printer reader slot is designed to be read only?

Comment: "Maybe the printer reader slot is designed to be read only?" Or does not understand ext. Generally I would expect the printer to only support FAT32 or exFat.

Comment: @Rinzwind The card is exFat as shown by Gparted. I think Canon and other printer manufactures do not spend a lot of effort to be more friendly with Linux.

Comment: Then this "I used chown to make me owner with read/write permissions."  makes NO sense. chown is not part of exfat. Or did you mean you changed the permissions of the mount point and not the content of the card?

Comment: I used chown before I knew it was exfat. Chown did not complain.